# Cucumber Java screenshots

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, screenshot, cucumber-java

Is there a way to take screenshots in between steps in Java Cucumber ?

I have the following scenario :

```
@Scenario_1
Given I log into url
And I see the home page is displayed in English //Take screenshot
And I click on 'Edit Profile'
And I see the language set to 'English' 
When I change the language to Chinese   //Take screenshot
And I navigate to home page
Then everything is displayed in Chinese //Take screenshot
```

I want to take screenshots for certain steps of the scenario.

I am currently taking a screenshot in the 'After' method.

```
@After()
public void execute_after_every_scenario(Scenario s) throws InterruptedException
{
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    final byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
    s.embed(screenshot, "image/png");

    driver.quit();
}
```

As expected, this is capturing the image for the last step only.

How can I capture the images for the other 2 steps and embed the image the same way as in the 'After' method ?

I tried to create a new method to take screenshots and call that method when needed. But can any other method , other than the one specified in 'After' , take scenario as an argument ?

```
take_screenshot(Scenario_1, driver);

public void take_screenshot(Scenario s,WebDriver driver)
{
    final byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
    s.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
}
```

How can I go about this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a screenshot step. Maybe something like this:

```
public class YourStepDefinitions {

    private Scenario myScenario;

    @Before()
    public void embedScreenshotStep(Scenario scenario) {

        myScenario = scenario;

    }

    @Then ("^I take a screenshot$")
    public void i_take_a_screenshot() throws Throwable {

        try {
            myScenario.write("Current Page URL is " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
            byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
            myScenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");  // Stick it in the report
        } catch (WebDriverException somePlatformsDontSupportScreenshots) {
            log.error(somePlatformsDontSupportScreenshots.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassCastException cce) {
            cce.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the Extent Report:**

```
Extent reports are more customizable than others.
Extent API can produce more interactive reports, a dashboard view, graphical view,         
capture screenshots at every test step, and emailable reports.
It can be easily integrated with frameworks like JUnit & TestNG.
```